# Sounds is broken after last update on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, 23.04

I do not know what happened and what package broken sounds, but now the sound became truncated, most of the frequencies disappeared.

**uname -a:**

```
Linux andrei-X570-GAMING-X 6.2.0-23-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed May 17 16:55:20 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what happened. And fix it.

This is configuration issue of pipware

so you need to reset configuration

```bash
rm -rdf $HOME/.local/state/wireplumber/
```

restart pipware service

```bash
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
```

And choose on the sound settings your main speakers

Comment: Seems in Ubuntu 23.10 the bug is still the same. The removal of wireplumper and restart of pipewire did the trick. Thx

Comment: Hm, but for me on Ubuntu 23.10 all works is fine.
I have this issue on Ubuntu 23.04 and early versions of Ubuntu 23.10, but now is fine.